# How do I extract each element in __NSArrayM?

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**I am using Firestore (still in beta) and my data structure is as follows:**

[image]

**I want to obtain each ingredient as a string to create objects of Ingredient class with their names. This is the method I am using:**

```
private func loadIngredients(){
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let recipeCollectionRef = db.collection("dishes").document((recipe?.name)!)
    recipeCollectionRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document {
            print("Document data: \(document.data())")
            print("\(document.data().values)")
            for value in document.data().values {
                print("Value: \(value)")
                print(type(of: value))
            }
        } else {
            print("Document does not exist")
        }
    }
}
```

**This currently yields:**

> Document data: ["ingredients": <__NSArrayM 0x60000025f2f0>(
>       banana,
>       oatmeal
>       )
>       , "level": easy]
>       LazyMapCollection, Any>(_base: ["ingredients": 
>       <__NSArrayM 0x60000065ad60>(
>       banana,
>       oatmeal
>       )
>       , "level": easy], _transform: (Function))
>       Value: (
>           banana,
>           oatmeal
>       )
>       __NSArrayM
>       Value: easy
>       NSTaggedPointerString

From what I understand based on reading Apple's documentation on Dictionaries:
My dictionary has type [String: Any] and in this case "ingredients" is the String acting as key and the value can be any object. The array that I am working with is a Mutable Array.

I am very confused as to how I can get that array and its respective elements. I have tried converting from LazyMapCollection to a String but that yields the whole array as a string. I also tried accessing the value by key "ingredients" but that does not work as "Cannot subscript a value of type `LazyMapCollection<[String : Any], Any>` with an index of type `String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated, `document.data()` is a dictionary (`[String:Any]`).

So start with that:

```
if let document = document, let data = document.data() as? [String:Any] {
}
```

Now if you want to access the ingredients array, you do:

```
if let ingredients = data["ingredients"] as? [String] {
}
```

All together you get:

```
private func loadIngredients(){
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let recipeCollectionRef = db.collection("dishes").document((recipe?.name)!)
    recipeCollectionRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, let data = document.data() as? [String:Any] {
            // Get the ingredients array
            if let ingredients = data["ingredients"] as? [String] {
                // do whatever you need with the array
            }

            // Get the "easy" value
            if let east = data["easy"] as? String {
            }
        } else {
            print("Document or its data does not exist")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just had the chance to test it out now. I can print out the name of each ingredient object now so it means that your solution works.

Comment: In case I want to initiate objects with several properties fetched at the same time. Can this part of your code:

if let ingredients = data["ingredients"] as? [String] {
                // do whatever you need with the array
            }

be expanded to this?

if let ingredients = data["ingredients"] as? [String], let ease = data["easy"] as? String {
// processing
}